# get data from XML using PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I currently have an XML file(http://redmine.something.com/projects.xml). I want to read that data to insert into my database using PHP function which I don't know how to write the function to get the data. Below is my example of that XML file structure:

```
<projects type="array" total_count="7" offset="0" limit="25">
    <project>
       <id>147</id>
       <name>012-003: online shop jakob schlaepfer</name>
       <identifier>012-003</identifier>
       <created_on>2012-02-01T09:14:29+07:00</created_on>
       <updated_on>2012-02-20T10:58:28+07:00</updated_on>
    </project>
</projects>
```

Any link or help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`SimpleXML`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Here are some [basic examples](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: I did it, but actually it displays error seems like demand the authorization to that url:                                                       Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://redmine.web-essentials.asia/projects.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required in /home/vannkorn/dev/testXML/index.php on line 3 Call Stack:....

Comment: That's a whole separate issue. Do you have permission to access that file?

Comment: You can add the authorization in the URL, e.g. http://user:password@www.example.org/secret_document.xml

Comment: It still doesn't work. It displays this error: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity `url`

Comment: I tried checking the Openssl extension in php.ini, and it's already enabled.